# Precision/Resolution of timing functions | How to quantify

Tags: javascript

Can anyone give advice as to the

[accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of timing in JavaScript?

I need to time user responses with a calculated accuracy and precision.

```
Date().getTime
```

was the function I was thinking about using to make measurements.  I imagine the accuracy is near perfect, but I want to calculate the precision.

I want to emulate a user using setTimeout() so I can calculate precision of getTime().

```
setTimeOut()
```

Do these two functions use the same clock?  If one varies say +10msec will the other as well effectively making my experiment to calculate precision useless?

Someone already did this:

http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Resolution Information

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363258

Comment: I think `getTime` should do it.

Comment: ...what are your requirements for accuracy and precision, other than you require accuracy and precision? `performance.now` will eventually allow recording of microseconds...  ...but nothing else will use those microseconds for scheduling purposes.

Comment: I imagine the accuracy is near perfect...but intuition tells me there are issues with precision...I want to calculate this.

Comment: ...accuracy of setTimeout is fundamentally flawed.  `setTimeout` does not fire at the exact time you schedule it for.  It fires as close to that time as it can, inside of the queue of everything that's going on in the browser's thread.

Comment: @Norguard...a browser is indeed one thread?  Is this correct?

Comment: well not for Chrome....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510483/will-a-browser-give-an-iframe-a-separate-thread-for-javascript

Comment: Yes. Everything happens on the same thread.  setTimeout queues itself within that thread after 'x'ms  So the accuracy of setTimeout is wholly dependent upon user-interaction, concurrent downloading, page-rendering, other scripts firing or loading or compiling...

Comment: After edit I think I understand... You want to know if the user sets a timeout of say 10ms when it ends `getTime` will report 10ms more exactly? What's the application of this?

Comment: @Norguard - What about getTime, is it flawed as well?

Comment: @elclanrs - I need precision b.c. it if for an experiment.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist that's different threads per open tab in your browser.  Pages are single-threaded.  That's why big-name developers constantly push for asynchronous programming.  I believe `getTime` is tied to your system's clock, directly in practically all implementations of browsers as far back as IE6.  How accurate it's going to be depends on what function it's in...  ...if you write something like `function doStuff ( var time = new Date().getTime(); doExpensiveDOMWork(); doRecursion(); return time; );` then it's going to be off, because it's time called and not time of return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this [article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now). It talks about the new [High resolution Timer](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html) and compares it with the current `Date` object.

> ```
> Date.now()         //  1337376068250
> performance.now()  //  20303.427000007
> ```

Basically there are two key points:

1. > performance.now() is a measurement of floating point milliseconds since that particular page started to load
2. > Perhaps less often considered is that Date, based on system time, isn't ideal for real user monitoring either. Most systems run a daemon which regularly synchronizes the time. It is common for the clock to be tweaked a few milliseconds every 15-20 minutes. At that rate about 1% of 10 second intervals measured would be inaccurate.

With `Date` you'll get miliseconds resolution, though the accuracy of it is not guaranteed. According to the [High resolution Timer](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html) specs:

> For certain tasks this definition of time may not be sufficient as it does not allow for sub-millisecond resolution and is subject to system clock skew.

I'd recommend you read both articles to get a clearer idea about this.

Comment: wow...something IE implemented before Safari...that is a first....http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing

Comment: Tony Gentilcore saying inaccurate means nothing if he doesn't quantify what he means by that.

Comment: I think he is quantifying it as that 1 in every 100 10 second intervals measured would deviate a few milliseconds. Of course, and as you say, everything is inaccurate. While getting sub-millisecond resolution you could start experiencing deviations caused by the instruction execution itself... in any case, I find this is a really interesting topic! :)