# Does main page share thread with iframes(or pop-ups) with different origin?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, event-loop

I found similar topic about [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510483/will-a-browser-give-an-iframe-a-separate-thread-for-javascript), and after reading additional conversations(like [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/loading-dev/MYeUv2FtGdw) one) I made a conclusion that iframes and pop-ups with same origin share main page's thread, to be able to communicate in sync mode.

But I still have some questions:

If I have an iframe with different origin and communicate with it by postmessage(that is async), does that limitation about one thread still exist? So, if I embeded iframe for example with google-tables into my page, would this piece of app overburden main page's event loop? And can it be avoided via using webview tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I got answer from another source and wanna share it with others who will be looking for this info. It's from article about event loop:

> Several Runtime communicating together A web worker or a **cross-origin
>   iframe** **has its own stack, heap, and message queue**. Two distinct
>   runtimes can only communicate through sending messages via the
>   postMessage method. This method adds a message to the other runtime if
>   the latter listens to message events.